# Error when getting AppDelegate instance in other UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, crash, appdelegate

Hello I have been seeing crash logs for my app which when I open in XCode highlights the following line

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

I am stumped as I cannot replicate this in XCode. What are the possible reasons the app may crash here?

This line is at `viewDidAppear()` and also at `viewDidLoad()` but 5 out of 5 crash reports all point to the line at `viewDidAppear()`

Edit:

Here's the crash log

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x0000000100531208 LoginViewController.initView() + 536 (LoginViewController.swift:107)
1   MyApp                           0x0000000100530d88 @objc LoginViewController.viewDidAppear(_:) + 112 (LoginViewController.swift:58)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018ee2973c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 840 (UIViewController.m:4471)
3   UIKit                           0x000000018f07a448 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 44 (UIViewController.m:5055)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018ee7f798 -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 92 (UIViewController.m:4793)
5   UIKit                           0x000000018f185990 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 564 (UIApplication.m:2528)
6   UIKit                           0x000000018f17b958 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 384 (UIApplication.m:2497)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018f18c68c __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 152 (UIApplication.m:9928)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851372bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20 (CFRunLoop.c:1840)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185136a7c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 264 (CFRunLoop.c:1881)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851347b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1224 (CFRunLoop.c:2922)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185054da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
12  GraphicsServices                0x000000018703a020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
13  UIKit                           0x000000018f074758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
14  MyApp                           0x0000000100424f3c main + 56 (BaseViewController.swift:19)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184ae5fc0 start + 4
```

Comment: What does the crash report say?

Comment: what 's in the crash log ?

Comment: added crash log

Comment: Is there any crash message?

Comment: @Lumialxk I could not find any crash message

Comment: Would you like to show some code in `LoginViewController `?

Comment: @Leon Possible reason for the crash on the mentioned line is `as!`. You should avoid use of `!`. Follow what @Lumialxk have mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The crash logs all point to this line

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

which is line 107 from my LoginViewController but the actual error is actually triggered by a line of code two lines prior (data related error). Don't know why the logs all point to line 107 though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this delegate is optional value.

> unowned(unsafe) open var delegate: UIApplicationDelegate?

So you should use it like this.

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    // code here
} else {
    // error handle
}
```

Comment: But how come I've never encountered this while in development? Also as I've stated in the question I call the same thing at viewDidLoad() and it does not crash there. Wouldn't it already crash there if this is a case of nil value?

Comment: @Leon If u use 'as!' to unwrap, it'll crash when got a nil value. If you want to replicate this bug, you should assign the device and os version.

Comment: well, I use 'as!' because I agree with the answer here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80810. This is probably up for debate but if my AppDelegate is nil then I'd most probably run into other sort of errors later so I'd rather let the app crash right there